# Axios Async-Await in React

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

I'm trying to do some get, and post request, somehow the state got updated late (it should be .get, then .post)

```
async componentDidMount() {

    const {destination, weight} = this.state;


    axios.get(`https://myapi`)
        .then(res => {
            const customer = res.data;

            this.setState({ customer,
                destination: customer[0].address[0].city,
            }
        })

   axios.post(`https://myapi`, {destination, weight})
        .then((post)=>{
          const delivery = post.data;
            this.setState({ delivery,
              cost: delivery[0].cost[0].value
             });
        });

        return post;
}
```

the state got updated, but somehow the post got error that destination should be filled. I find the solution of this is to use async await. I try to implement it but it doesn't work.

here's what i've tried

```
async componentDidMount() {

        const {destination, weight} = this.state;


        axios.get(`https://myapi`)
            .then(res => {
                const customer = res.data;

                this.setState({ customer,
                    destination: customer[0].address[0].city,
                }
            })

const post = await axios.post(`https://api.cashless.vip/api/cost`, {destination, weight})
            .then((post)=>{
          console.log(this.state.destination);
              const delivery = post.data;
                this.setState({ delivery,
                  cost: delivery[0].cost[0].value
                 });
            });

            return post;
}
```

i tried to console log the state of destination and yes it's indeed updated. am i doing async await wrong? thank you for your help!

Comment: have You tried to do it with Promise?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: If you're using `await`, I don't see why you even need `then`.  The `await` is supposed unwrap the `then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try{
   let res = await axios.get(`https://myapi`);
   if (res) {
     const customer = res.data;
     this.setState({ customer,
        destination: customer[0].address[0].city,
     });
     const postRes = await axios.post(`https://api.cashless.vip/api/cost`);
     if (postRes) {
       const delivery = post.data;
         this.setState({ delivery,
           cost: delivery[0].cost[0].value
         });
     }
   }
}catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

If you want to use post outside if its upto you.

Comment: Why if (res) ? You should add async to this block, otherwise await won't do the trick

Comment: yes async has to be added on the function definition, i think that was not the question. About if(res), get could return empty response which includes " " or null so you do not set state in that case.

Comment: it works just fine when i put the POST outside the if. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: it works just fine when i put the POST outside the if. Thanks a lot!!!!